# Billing access denied, tho Ive granted all access to an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I currently cant watch or edit Billing (through IAM User Access to Billing Information) because the AWS console says that I dont have permissions.
I am the only user in the account, with a full IAM access in the group and directly on the user as well, including a the AWS Billing policy and fullBuillingAccess (that I created). But when I navigate to billing I cannot look further:

You Need Permissions
You don't have permission to access billing information for this account. Contact your AWS administrator if you need help. If you are an AWS administrator, you can provide permissions for your users or groups by making sure that (1) this account allows IAM and federated users to access billing information and (2) you have the required IAM permissions.

I granted access as a user but I cant do clause 1 for it directly prompt me this message.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The answer:
After further checking I found out that only a ROOT USER can enable billing access to IAM users.

If you have the same problem you need to ask the root user or login as root the enable access.